# insert a string to a list variables in text file [use sed]

Tags: sed, text

I want to add `zsh-autosuggestions` plugin to `~/.zshrc` by script.

## original text:

```
plugins=(git)
```

or

```
 plugins=(git
 some1
 some2)
```

## target :

```
plugins=(git
zsh-autosuggestions)
```

1. This doesn't work.

   ```
   sed -i  's/^plugins=\(([^\)]*)\)/plugins=\(\1\nzsh-autosuggestions\n\)/' ~/.zshrc
   ```

   I am confused, I think this `([^\)]*)`  is group 1, but why it not work
2. but remove first group's `()`

   ```
   sed -i  's/^plugins=\([^\)]*\)/plugins=\(\1\nzsh-autosuggestions\n\)/' ~/.zshrc
   ```

   turn out to

   ```
   plugins=((git
   zsh-autosuggestions
   )
   )
   ```

   I have escaped the `()` by `\`, why it became group 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Sed`** solution:

Sample `~/.zshrc` contents:

```
param=val1
plugins=(git)
param2=val2

plugins=(git
some1
some2)
param3=val3
```

---

```
sed '/^plugins=/ N;N; s/\(=([^)]*\))/\1\nzsh-autosuggestions)/' ~/.zshrc
```

- `N` - add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space
- `\(...\)` - regex captured group; should be escaped with `\` in *BRE* to enable its special meaning

---

The output:

```
param=val1
plugins=(git
zsh-autosuggestions)
param2=val2

plugins=(git
some1
some2
zsh-autosuggestions)
param3=val3
```

Comment: could you explain what `N;N;` and `=` means?  In python or javascript,  once `()` aprear(witout escape) would be considered as a group. Seems it is not so in sed.

Comment: @Mithril, see my explanation

Comment: emmm, it is still confusing ...  because I usually write regex in python, the sed match group is wrong in my viewing,  https://regex101.com/r/DRChkE/1  .   I think I need ask a question how to make sed regex work as the common standard(python or javascript , java).

Comment: @Mithril, https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Overview-of-basic-regular-expression-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Below command works fine for me

---

Command

```
 echo "plugins=(git)" | sed "s/(.*[^)]/&\nzsh-autosuggestions/g"
```

---

Output

```
plugins=(git
zsh-autosuggestions)
```