# How to make sed regex syntax work as python or javascript?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, standard

I have asked a question [insert a string to a list variables in text file [use sed]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415165/insert-a-string-to-a-list-variables-in-text-file-use-sed/415167#415167)

In which @RomanPerekhrest showed me a different regex syntax.

`\(=([^)]*\))` can capture `[^)]*` as group 1 . This is confusting for me .

You can check the result on https://regex101.com/r/DRChkE/2

[image]
[image]

---

https://regex101.com/r/LItVNg/1

[image]

This `\(([^\)]*)\)` is the correct one in my mind, but it is broken in sed.

So I wonder how to make sed use the regex syntax standard as python or javascript (common standard in many languages).

Comment: also worth reading: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html

Comment: I would really like a version of sed that could do javascript extended regex. Like the ones in https://regexcrossword.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Perl-style aka PCRE regular expressions but that isn't a POSIX conforming syntax and not supported by typical implementations of the standard command-line tools like `sed`. What is supported are the syntax known as Basic Regular Expression (BRE) and Extended Regular Expression (ERE). In `sed` the former is the default and the latter is enabled with `-E` (in GNU sed `-r` also works).

You'll occasionally see versions of standard tools with some support for PCRE (e.g. GNU's `grep` has the `-P` flag) but this is the exception not the norm.

See the [Standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards) section of Wikipedia's regex page for details.